Redis or database for cache, distribiuted lock, signalR scale-out?
I am evaluating whether to use Redis or alternative methods for caching, distributed locking, and scaling SignalR applications in our new system. Despite my tech lead's skepticism towards Redis, I am exploring various perspectives to inform our architectural choices. Here are the details and considerations for each component:

Caching:

Requirements: Highly up-to-date data is essential.
Data Characteristics: Most keys involve a few hundred KBs, with rare instances up to 2-3 MB.
Structure: Multi-tenant database categorized by [companyname] and [company_name][storeX], with several hundred keys per store and expected growth to several hundred stores within a year.
-Approaches:
--Redis: Key, for example, in the format [company][store][group/groups]_specific_name
For GET requests, check if the key exists; if yes, return the data from Redis; if no, retrieve and parse data from the database, then store it in Redis.
For POST/PUT/DELETE requests, process the data, save it, and subsequently remove related keys from Redis for the affected company and/or stores.
E.g. a change in store settings removes all keys affected by those settings i.e. had a "Settings" group
--Database: Use a dedicated cache table within each [company_name] database.
Key format and action analogously. Using triggers to clear the cache is out, because the company's main database and store databases can affect each other in the results of requests.

Distributed Locking:

-Redis: Implement using a library such as RedLock.net.
-Database: Utilize a lock table with columns like [store][locked]. Check for existing locks before proceeding; if unlocked, set a GUID, verify it, process the data, and then clear the lock. If locked, retry after a delay.

Scaling SignalR (Websocket Notifications):

-Redis: Employ Redis as a backplane using a method recommended by Microsoft.
-Alternatives:
--Maintain a single instance of the SignalR application.
--Replace websockets with periodic polling every few seconds.
